# Floating text to the right inside of textarea

Tags: css, text, textarea, alignment

I know this may seem like a silly question, but I never had to do this until now. Is there a way to float text to the right while inside of a form text area?

Comment: can you show your codes and css in your textarea?

Comment: @bot It would be a `<textarea>` tag with text inside =p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "float", but if you mean to just right align the text then you can do it like this:

```
textarea{
    text-align:right;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/atQ42/)

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I meant musefan! Ty very much :)
Not sure why that didn't dawn on me.

Comment: why wrap="off"   text-align:right; useless？

Answer (score 0):

Here: Try this 
Give your text area an id and edit its text-align on css. Something like this

```
<textarea id="area">Test</textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
#area
{
text-align:right;
}
```

or musefan answer will do it if you want that all your textarea will align-right but if you want just one textarea you could use mine. :)

Comment: why wrap="off" text-align:right; useless？